# How can I Update data in modal using Vue js and Laravel SPA?

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to Vue js. I created my Create form page and it's working, I want to work on the Update now. I have the Edit form in a modal and the correct data from the User is there. When I click update, none of my "File" type Inputs are being uploaded and I get a ton of errors. FYI, I've created 3 Tables to hold all of the different Media files, Videos, Resumes and Photos and in the candidate_profiles table I have the following columns for these: photo_id, resume_id, video_one_id, video_two_id, video_three_id.

Here is a screenshot of my form:
[image]

Here is a screenshot of editProfileData array in Vue console. I just noticed when I upload a video file, photo resume whatever, it still says the ids and doesn't change to the filename. You'll see all of the fields have numbers in them:
[image]

ProfileIndex.vue Modal:

```
<b-modal ref="editProfileModal" id="modal-1" title="Update Profile" hide-footer>
            <form v-on:submit.prevent="updateProfile">
                <b-form-group label="Upload Profile Photo (optional)" label-for="photo_id">
                    <b-form-file
                        id="photo_id"
                        placeholder="Choose a file..."
                        @change="editAttachImage"
                        accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png"
                    ></b-form-file>
                </b-form-group>

                <b-form-group
                    label="Date of Birth"
                    label-for="date-of-birth"
                >
                    <b-form-input
                        type="date"
                        v-model="editProfileData.date_of_birth"
                        id="date-of-birth"
                    >
                    </b-form-input>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="errors.date_of_birth">{{ errors.date_of_birth[0] }}</div>
                </b-form-group>
                <b-form-group
                    label="Employemnt Type"
                    label-for="employment-type"
                >
                    <b-form-radio-group
                        id="employment-type"
                        v-model="editProfileData.employment_type"
                        :options="options"
                        name="employment-type"
                    >
                    </b-form-radio-group>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="errors.employment_type">{{ errors.employment_type[0] }}</div>
                </b-form-group>

                <b-form-group label="Resume" label-for="resume_id">
                    <b-form-file
                        id="resume_id"
                        placeholder="Choose a file..."
                        @change="editAttachResume"
                        accept=".doc,.docx"
                    ></b-form-file>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="errors.resume_id">{{ errors.resume_id[0] }}</div>
                </b-form-group>

                <h4 class="mb-3">Please attach a few short videos (30 seconds max) for a better chance of being noticed. (optional)</h4>

                <b-form-group label="1. Tell us a little about yourself: (attach video)" label-for="video_one_id">
                    <b-form-file
                        id="video_one_id"
                        placeholder="Choose a file..."
                        @change="editAttachVideoOne"
                        accept=".mp4, .mpeg4"
                    ></b-form-file>
                </b-form-group>

                <b-form-group label="2. Tell us about your past work experiences: (attach video)" label-for="video_two_id">
                    <b-form-file
                        id="video_two_id"
                        placeholder="Choose a file..."
                        @change="editAttachVideoTwo"
                        accept=".mp4, .mpeg4"
                    ></b-form-file>
                </b-form-group>

                <b-form-group label="3. What sets you apart?: (attach video)" label-for="video_three_id">
                    <b-form-file
                        id="video_three_id"
                        placeholder="Choose a file..."
                        @change="editAttachVideoThree"
                        accept=".mp4, .mpeg4"
                    ></b-form-file>
                </b-form-group>

                <b-form-group label="Experience" label-for="experience">
                    <b-form-textarea
                        id="experience"
                        v-model="editProfileData.experience"
                        :state="profileData.experience.length <= 1100"
                        placeholder="Tell us a little about your experience..."
                        :rows="10"
                        :max-rows="12"
                    >
                    </b-form-textarea>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="errors.experience">{{ errors.experience[0] }}</div>
                </b-form-group>
                <b-form-group label="Skills" label-for="skills">
                    <b-form-textarea
                        id="skills"
                        v-model="editProfileData.skills"
                        :state="profileData.skills.length <= 350"
                        placeholder="List your skills..."
                        :rows="4"
                        :max-rows="6"
                    >
                    </b-form-textarea>
                    <b-form-invalid-feedback v-if="errors.skills" id="photo_id">{{ errors.skills[0] }}</b-form-invalid-feedback>
                </b-form-group>
                <b-row>
                    <b-col class="text-left">
                        <b-button variant="light">Cancel</b-button>
                    </b-col>
                    <b-col class="text-right">
                        <b-button type="submit" variant="success" class="mr-2"
                        ><i class="mdi mdi-check-circle"></i> Update</b-button
                        >
                    </b-col>
                </b-row>
            </form>
            </form>
        </b-modal>
```

ProfileIndex.vue js:

```
<script>
    import * as groupedService from '../../../services/grouped_data_service.js';
    import * as profileService from '../../../services/candidate_profile_service.js';

    export default {
        name: "candidateProfileIndex",

        data() {
            return {
                profiles: [],
                video_one: [],
                video_two: [],
                video_three: [],
                resumes: [],
                photos: [],

                profile: [],

                options: [
                    { text: "Full Time", value: "Full Time" },
                    { text: "Part Time", value: "Part Time" },
                ],

                profileData: {
                    photo_id: [],
                    employment_type: "Full Time",
                    date_of_birth: "",
                    experience: "",
                    skills: "",
                    resume_id: [],
                    video_one_id: [],
                    video_two_id: [],
                    video_three_id: []
                },

                editProfileData: {
                    photo_id: [],
                    resume_id: [],
                    video_one_id: [],
                    video_two_id: [],
                    video_three_id: []
                },
                errors: {}
            };
        },

        mounted() {
            this.loadGroupedData();
        },

        methods: {
            loadGroupedData: async function() {
                try {
                    const response = await groupedService.loadGroupedData();
                    this.resumes = response.data.resumes;
                    this.video_one = response.data.video_one;
                    this.video_two = response.data.video_two;
                    this.video_three = response.data.video_three;
                    this.photos = response.data.photos;
                    this.profiles = response.data.profiles;
                } catch (error) {
                    this.$toast.error("Some error occurred, please refresh!");
                }
            },

            hideEditProfileModal() {
                this.$refs.editProfileModal.hide();
            },

            showEditProfileModal() {
                this.$refs.editProfileModal.show();
            },

            editProfile(profile) {
                this.editProfileData = {...profile};
                this.showEditProfileModal();
            },

            editAttachImage(evt) {
                const file = evt.target.files[0];
                let reader = new FileReader();
                reader.addEventListener('load', function() {

                }.bind(this), false);
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            },
            editAttachResume(evt) {
                const file = evt.target.files[0];
                let reader = new FileReader();
                reader.addEventListener('load', function() {

                }.bind(this), false);
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            },
            editAttachVideoOne(evt) {
                const file = evt.target.files[0];
                let reader = new FileReader();
                reader.addEventListener('load', function() {

                }.bind(this), false);
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            },
            editAttachVideoTwo(evt) {
                const file = evt.target.files[0];
                let reader = new FileReader();
                reader.addEventListener('load', function() {

                }.bind(this), false);
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            },
            editAttachVideoThree(evt) {
                const file = evt.target.files[0];
                let reader = new FileReader();
                reader.addEventListener('load', function() {

                }.bind(this), false);
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            },
            updateProfile: async function() {
                try {
                    const formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append('photo_id', this.editProfileData.photo_id);
                    formData.append('employment_type', this.editProfileData.employment_type);
                    formData.append('date_of_birth', this.editProfileData.date_of_birth);
                    formData.append('experience', this.editProfileData.experience);
                    formData.append('skills', this.editProfileData.skills);
                    formData.append('resume_id', this.editProfileData.resume_id);
                    formData.append('video_one_id', this.editProfileData.video_one_id);
                    formData.append('video_two_id', this.editProfileData.video_two_id);
                    formData.append('video_three_id', this.editProfileData.video_three_id);
                    formData.append('_method', 'put');

                    const response = await profileService.updateProfile(this.editProfileData.id, formData);
                    this.profiles.map(profile => {
                        if (profile.id == response.data.id) {
                            for (let key in response.data) {
                                profile[key] = response.data[key];
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    this.hideEditProfileModal();
                    this.$toast.success("Profile created Successfully!");
                } catch (error) {
                    this.$toast.error(error.response.data.message);
                }
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here are my errors:

```
app.js:2156 POST http://highrjobsadminlte.test/api/candidate/profile/1 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

```
Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "content". Expected String, Object, Function, got Undefined
```

```
Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"
```

```
Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

I've been struggling for 2 and half days on this, if someone can please help me.

Comment: Is your question related to mysql/larabel/crud in any way? If not - please remove the non-relevant tags.

Comment: I'm using Mysql, Laravel and my question is related to CRUD, but it's mostly a Vue question. Should I remove them?

Comment: Make sure your question is focused and remove everything that is not related to that. If your code for example has 100 lines and only 5 are relevant - remove the other 95. The more focus your question is - the faster you will get answers (and more people will actually spend time on it).

Comment: The first error actually answers your question: `http://highrjobsadminlte.test/api/candidate/profile/1` returns `500 (Internal Server Error)`. It's broken. Because of that, the data you expect from that call doesn't return and there's a cascade of errors from methods which try to dig into the data that's never returned. Fix the the problem on the server (basically figure out why it breaks) and, most likely, they will all go away.

Comment: I created a service to fetch the route. ```export function updateProfile(id, data) {
    return httpFile().post(`candidate/profile/${id}`, data);
}``` Why am I getting error?